# Change in Covariance from changes in Variances

Tags: variance, covariance, stochastic-processes

I wish to estimate how the covariance of two vectors $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{B}$, that come from stochastic processes, changes after transforming $\boldsymbol{A}$ (and or $\boldsymbol{B}$, using a different transformation) in a not completely known way. I know the original values of $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{B}$ and how those transformations changes their variances. It can be assumed that the transformations do not change the expected values (which will be zero in most cases).

I guess that there is no general exact solution, but maybe something can be said.
My best attempt is as follows: If the variance of $\boldsymbol{A}$ after the transformation is the original variance multiplied by $a^2$, and the variance of $\boldsymbol{B}$ after the transformation is the original variance multiplied by $b^2$, the covariance after the transformation may be close to $\text{Cov}(a \boldsymbol{A},b\boldsymbol{B})$

The supposition above worked fine in some numerical tests that I performed playing with sinusoidal functions. But I do not know what are the hidden assumptions for it to work, or if there are more general results.

To be clearer, the problem is that of the first paragraph, but any partial/approximated solution or clarification on the special case solution mentioned in paragraph two  is welcomed. My goal is to arrive at an at least an approximate solution to a problem involving objects whose positions fluctuate in time.

Thanks in advance.